# Webauthn conditional ui not working in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, safari, webauthn, passkey

I am trying to implement authentication with Webauthn. After verifying platform and browser support using the suggested methods `window.PublicKeyCredential.isUserVerifyingPlatformAuthenticatorAvailable()` and `await window.PublicKeyCredential.isConditionalMediationAvailable()`, I add the pending request to navigator.credentials:

```js
let credentials = await window.navigator.credentials.get({
            signal: abortSignal,
            publicKey: {
                // Don't do this in production!
                challenge: new Uint8Array([1, 2, 3, 4]),
                allowCredentials: []
            },
            mediation: "conditional"
        });
```

My form:

```html
<form>
    <label for="login-username">Username:</label>
    <input name="username" id="login-username" value="" autocomplete="username webauthn" autofocus/>
    <label for="password">Fake password:</label>
    <input id="password" value="" required type="password" autocomplete="password webauthn"/>
    <div class="button-box">
      <button id="login" type="submit">
        <strong>Log-in</strong>
      </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**I am expecting to see a drop-down/popover from the browser, as soon as I click in either the username or password input fields, that allows me to choose a passkey from a different device, but I do not see this in Chrome (Version 117.0.5938.132).**

Safari however works as expected. What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:**
So I tested it out using a simple index.html-file with all the code needed in there, it looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Conditional UI</title>
    <script>
      window.PublicKeyCredential.isUserVerifyingPlatformAuthenticatorAvailable().then(
              result => {
                if (!result) {
                  console.log("No platform authenticator found. If your OS does not come with one, try using devtools to set one up.");
                }
              }
      );


      let abortController;
      let abortSignal;

      let startConditionalRequest = async () => {
        if (window.PublicKeyCredential.isConditionalMediationAvailable) {
          console.log("Conditional UI is understood by the browser");
          if (!await window.PublicKeyCredential.isConditionalMediationAvailable()) {
            console.log("Conditional UI is understood by your browser but not available");
            return;
          }
        } else {
          if (!navigator.credentials.conditionalMediationSupported) {
            console.log("Your browser does not implement Conditional UI (are you running the right chrome/safari version with the right flags?)");
            return;
          } else {
            console.log("This browser understand the old version of Conditional UI feature detection");
          }
        }
        abortController = new AbortController();
        abortSignal = abortController.signal;

        try {
          let credential = await window.navigator.credentials.get({
            signal: abortSignal,
            publicKey: {
              // Don't do this in production!
              challenge: new Uint8Array([1, 2, 3, 4]),
              allowCredentials: []
            },
            mediation: "conditional"
          });
          if (credential) {
            let username = String.fromCodePoint(...new Uint8Array(credential.response.userHandle));
            console.log(username);
          } else {
            console.log("Credential returned null");
          }
        } catch (error) {
          if (error.name == "AbortError") {
            console.log("request aborted");
            return;
          }
          console.log(error.toString());
        }
      }

      startConditionalRequest();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form>
    <label for="login-username">Username:</label>
    <input name="username" id="login-username" value="" autocomplete="username webauthn" autofocus/>
    <label for="password">Fake password:</label>
    <input id="password" value="" required type="password" autocomplete="password webauthn"/>
    <div class="button-box">
      <button id="login" type="submit">
        <strong>Log-in</strong>
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now that works perfectly when I open it in any browser. But if I try to do the same hosting with vite dev-server, or if I build a react-app it works in Safari, but not chrome. Could this have anything to do with shadow-dom or something?

Does anyone have this working for a react-app in chrome? Would love to hear how you did it.

Answer (score 0):

> Could this have anything to do with shadow-dom or something?

Chrome password autofill doesn't currently work inside shadow DOM from what I can see: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1404106

Comment: So it seems. Hope they will fix this soon, it is a total showstopper for modern apps. Thank you.